# Do i have to keep `DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` as the device ID for ads

Tags: java, android

Im new to using adMob with android studio and I have a quick question. For the device ID in the adRequest i wrote `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` and everything works when i run the app on genymotion the ads come up etc. and it also works when I test on an actualy phone device. I wanted to ask though do i keep `DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR`as the device Id or do I change to something else so the ads come up on every phone that has my app?

```
AdView adview = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: I see that you doesn't accept any answer for all of your questions ... wierd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi Let me explain inshort

Ads shows when you keep Device_Id_Emultor, if you remove also it shows
difference is , when you keep id it shows on test ads, you wont get earnings from it
when you testing your app keep the id, when you publishing to market comment or remove device id

For Testing

```
AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
```

For Publishing/earning real ads

```
AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder(); //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
```

Comment: Is it a problem to keep it, as the real users will not be using an emulator?